# Send message to MQ using Jmeter

Tags: jms, jmeter, ibm-mq, performance-testing

I want to send message to a remote IBM MQ using Jmeter for performance testing. I went through this [link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0808_vandekuil/0808_vandekuil.html). But it requires the JNDI specific details like, QueueConnection Factory, JNDI Name Request queue, Initial Context Factory & Provider URL. Whereas the queu details i have are Qmanager, Qname, hostname, channel, port as given in the code shared in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12108372/issues-with-connecting-to-ibm-mq-7-5-using-java). Do these properties have any relation? Can i configure the Jmeter JMS test using the queue details i have?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ayushi, Did you find an easy way to make this work? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Mandy, i did not find any way to make it work. Moreover, this wasn't required later on in my project, so stopped looking for the solution.

Comment: Ayushi, Thanks a lot for responding. Btw, I was able to make this work  using the directions provided in [link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0808_vandekuil/0808_vandekuil.html). the only addition is that i had to copy all the MQ jars from Websphere MQ installation into JMeter/lib.

Answer (score 1):

The first link you gave has a description using Java JMS/MQ and the second shows Java MQ (non-JMS).

JMS is just an abstraction layer.  In simple terms, JMS is like giving everything a nick-name.  A QCF (QueueConnectionFactory) is simply an object that has all of the information to connect to a queue manager.

i.e.

```
DEFINE QCF(myQCF) QMANAGER(MQWT1) CHANNEL(TEST.CHL) HOSTNAME(127.0.0.1) PORT(1415) TRANSPORT(CLIENT) FAILIFQUIESCE(YES)
```

A JMS queue is just a nick-name to an MQ queue.

```
DEFINE Q(test.q) QUEUE(TEST.Q1) QMANAGER(MQWT1) TARGCLIENT(JMS) FAILIFQUIESCE(YES)
```

Therefore, in your JMS code you simply reference your QCF (i.e. myQCF) and the JMS queue (i.e. test.q) and you are good to go.

```
Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ""file:/C:/JNDI-Directory");

try
{
   Context ctx = new InitialContext(env);

   QueueConnectionFactory cf = (QueueConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup("myQCF");
   Queue q = (Queue) ctx.lookup("test.q");
}
catch (NamingException e)
{
   System.err.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done via the beanshell as well. You can directly access the queue manager via the api, or via exposing the queue via a jms binding. The first is more simple and does not require the MQ client installation.