# Connecting to IBM MQ from Java client is failing with MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2035'

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I have a IBM MQ version 7.5 installation in windows 7. I have created a queue manager, channel and listener using the following commands.

```
//CREATE THE QUEUE MANAGER
crtmqm.exe PG3RT1

//START THE QUEUE MANAGER AS INTERACTIVE
strmqm.exe -si PG3RT1

//CONNECT AS SCRIPT CONSOLE
runmqsc.exe PG3RT1

//CREATE THE CHANNEL TO APPLICATION CONNECTIVITY
DEFINE CHANNEL(PG3RT1.CHANNEL) CHLTYPE(SVRCONN) TRPTYPE(TCP)

//CREATE THE LISTENER 
DEFINE LISTENER(LISTENER.PG3RT1) TRPTYPE(TCP) PORT(1414)

//START THE LISTENER
START LISTENER(LISTENER.PG3RT1)
```

Now i am trying to connect to the Queue Manager using following java client.
connection is rejected with the following error.

```
    15:06:52.175 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR c.b.c.s.s.m.MQUtil - MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2035'.
com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2035'.
        at com.ibm.mq.MQManagedConnectionJ11.<init>(MQManagedConnectionJ11.java:230)
        at com.ibm.mq.MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11._createManagedConnection(MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.java:553)
        at com.ibm.mq.MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.createManagedConnection(MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.java:593)
        at com.ibm.mq.StoredManagedConnection.<init>(StoredManagedConnection.java:96)
        at com.ibm.mq.MQSimpleConnectionManager.allocateConnection(MQSimpleConnectionManager.java:198)
        at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.obtainBaseMQQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:893)
        at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.procure(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:780)
        at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.constructQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:729)
        at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.createQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:177)
        at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager.<init>(MQQueueManager.java:745)
        at com.bcs.cas.sach.simulator.mq.MQUtil.init(MQUtil.java:52)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
```

Can anyone advise why the connection is failing. 
Do i need to enable remote administration on the queue manager?

Following is the code fragement i used for connection

```
public void init(){
    MQEnvironment.hostname = hostName;
    MQEnvironment.port = Integer.valueOf(port);
    MQEnvironment.channel = serverChannelName;
    MQEnvironment.properties.put(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES);
    LOGGER.info("queueManagerName: " + queueManagerName);
    LOGGER.info("hostName: " + hostName);
    LOGGER.info("serverChannelName: " + serverChannelName);
    LOGGER.info("port: " + port);
    //initialize the connection pool
    MQPoolToken token = MQEnvironment.addConnectionPoolToken();
    try {
        mqQueueManager = new MQQueueManager(queueManagerName, MQEnvironment.properties);
        LOGGER.info("mqQueueManager: " + mqQueueManager);
    } catch (MQException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

Comment: The details of the error should be in MQ error log. Can you provide that as well?

Comment: Reason codes (v8.0): https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.tro.doc/q040710_.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MQRC 2035 is MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED. The reason this was returned can be found in the AMQERR log on the queue manager.

As CHLAUTH hasn't been configured, and is on by default, I expect you're not able to connect as you're not passing the CHLAUTH rules.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. CHLAUTH was by default enabled in the queue manager. I disabled the CHLAUTH and now i am able to connect.

Answer (score 2):

It is quite likely that this is an authorization issue. The easiest is to look at the return code and interpret

`mqrc 2035  returns MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED`

One of the reasons for it could be permissions. This can be resolved either by setting the right privilges on the QueueManager (setmqaut) , then on the channel enable the user with you are connecting to MQ to authorize as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12108372/issues-with-connecting-to-ibm-mq-7-5-using-java) . Post this you can use the code to connect by adding userId to the MQEnvironment and go

You can also refer this [technote](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21166937) for information.

Answer (score 0):

We are using clearing the authentication setting on manager by *runmqsc*:

> SET CHLAUTH('CNL_NAME') TYPE(BLOCKUSER) USERLIST(ALLOWANY)
>
> ALTER QMGR CONNAUTH(' ')
>
> REFRESH SECURITY TYPE(CONNAUTH)

in case of development. Or proper setting of credentials:

```
QueueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection(props.get(PROP.USER), props.get(PROP.PASSWD));
```

for JMS or:

```
...
MQEnvironment.userID = uid;
MQEnvironment.password = passwd;
new MQQueueManager(isQueueMgr);
```

for native com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager.